# $_POST array is empty and I got undefined variable errors

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Sorry to ask it again, but I checked almost all the q&a's on the topic and still couldn't solve it. Here is my form.php and creditform.php

Edit1.**Changed the .get to .post**

Edit2.**I'm getting errors of undefined variable  "name" "email" "address" "income" etc (in short for all of them) in creditform.php**
What I want to do is just insert all the inputs into the table in db.

HTML

```
<!-- End crumbs-->
            <div class="container wrap wow fadeInUp">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 left-app">
            <form id="form" action="php/creditform.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email"  name="email" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Address"  name="address" required>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Monthly income before taxes"  name="income" required>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Amount Needed"  name="amount_needed" required>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Phone"  name="phone" required>
             <div class="row">
             <div class="container">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"></div></div>
             <div id="result"></div>  
            </form> 
            </div>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function($) {
                   'use strict';

                $('#form').submit(function(event) {  
                   event.preventDefault();  
                   var url = $(this).attr('action');  
                   var datos = $(this).serialize();  
                   $.post(url, datos, function(resultado) {  
                   $('#result').html(resultado);  
                   });  
               });
                </script>
```

FORM.PHP

```
<?php

include('db.config.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $name = $email = $address = $income = $amount_needed = $phone = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
   $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
   $address = addslashes($_POST['address']);
   $income = addslashes($_POST['income']);
   $amount_needed = addslashes($_POST['amount_needed']);
   $phone = addslashes($_POST['phone']);

// check form fields
if(empty($name)){
    $error .= 'Enter name <br />';
}
if(empty($email)){
    $error .= 'Enter email <br />';
}
// check if errors exist
if(!empty($error)){
    echo $error;    
} else {
    // process form as normal   

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . DBN . "`.`creditapp` (`name`, `email`, `address`, `income`, `amount_needed`, `phone`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$address', '$income', '$amount_needed', '$phone')";
    $db->Query($sql);
}
}
} 
print_r($_POST);

?>
```

CREDITFORM.PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $address = $_POST['address'];
   $income = $_POST['income'];
   $amount_needed = $_POST['amount_needed'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
}
print_r($_POST);


?>
```

It's obvious that I'm missing something, please correct me...
Thanks for your time

Comment: Please post your rendered `<form>`'s HTML.

Comment: so... what is or isn't happening?

Comment: What's `php/creditform.php`?  Why are you using `$.get(` in your submit handler?  That should be `$.post(`.

Comment: Please indent your code

Comment: When posting with jquery (you're currently using GET, but i'm sure you'll fix that soon enough..) the submit button will not be included, so `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` will always be false.

Comment: edited the code, wrote the error i'm getting, thanks everyone really

Comment: @KevinB okay...So how should I post it?

Comment: So, what was undefined?

Comment: name - email - etc. all of them are giving undefined variable errors in creditform.php

Comment: What's the *exact* error message?  Can you copy & paste the full error message?  Is it "undefined index" or "undefined variable"?

Comment: Your javascript code is missing )}; at the end. (not relevent to the error you are getting)

Comment: **WARNING**: `addslashes` is not an adequate solution for [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I practiced more on ajax - json - php and in the end this was my solution and my latest code.

Thanks for all answers and suggestions. Hope this also helps to someone.

Still open to any kind of advice to improve.

```
<?php

include('db.config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
$email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
$address = addslashes($_POST['address']);
$income = addslashes($_POST['income']);
$amount_needed = addslashes($_POST['amount_needed']);
$phone = addslashes($_POST['phone']);

// process form as normal   

$sql = "INSERT INTO `" . DBN . "`.`creditapp` (`name`, `email`, `address`, `income`, `amount_needed`, `phone`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$address', '$income', '$amount_needed', '$phone')";
$db->Query($sql);

die();

<div class="container wrap wow fadeInUp">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 left-app">
        <form id="form" action="creditapp.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" required>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email"  name="email" id="email" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Address"  name="address" id="address" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Monthly income before taxes" id="income" name="income" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Amount Needed"  name="amount_needed" id="amount_needed" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Phone"  name="phone" id="phone" required>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button sub"></div>
        </div>
        </form> 
        </div>

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.sub').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val(),
            email = $('#email').val(),
            address = $('#address').val(),
            income = $('#income').val(),
            amount_needed = $('#amount_needed').val(),
            phone = $('#phone').val();


        $.ajax({
            url: "creditapp.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                address: address,
                income: income,
                amount_needed: amount_needed,
                phone: phone,
                submit: "submit"
            }

            }).done(function(msg){
              $('.right-info').html('<pre>' + msg + '</pre>');
            })
       })
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to send a `POST` request for the `$_POST` array to have anything in it.

```
$.get(url, datos, function(resultado) {  
    $('#result').html(resultado);  
});
```

This sends a `GET` request (check `$_GET`).  You want to use `$.post` here instead.

```
$.post(url, datos, function(resultado) {  
    $('#result').html(resultado);  
});
```

Comment: I changed that but the thing is I'm getting undefined variable errors for creditform.php

Comment: Someone stated in the comments on the question that the `submit` button might not be included in `serialize()`.  Try `$.post(url, datos+'&submit=submit'), function(`.

Comment: What's the *exact* error message?  Is it "undefined index" or "undefined variable"?

Comment: its undefined variable

Comment: Which line is giving this error?  Show us the *EXACT* error message and the line of code it's on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple **Ajax call to a Php** File by an event : Click on a button.

In your example you must use POST method because you use :

`$_POST['something'];`

**Javascript client side :**

```
 $("body").on("click", "#mybutton", function() {
            var mydata = $("#form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/api.php",
                data: {data : mydata},
                timeout: 6e3,
                error: function(a, b) {
                    if ("timeout" == b) $("#err-timedout").slideDown("slow"); else {
                        $("#err-state").slideDown("slow");
                        $("#err-state").html("An error occurred: " + b);
                    }
                },
                success: function(a) {
                    var e = $.parseJSON(a);
                    if (true == e["success"]) {
                        $("#result").html(e['message']);
                        // here is what you want, callback Php response content in Html DOM
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

**Next in your Php code simply do after any success function :**

```
if ($result) {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'success' => true,
                'msg' => "Nice CallBack by Php sent to client Side by Ajax Call"
            ));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is with your javascript. You wait for the submit and than you do an ajax **GET** request, you need a **POST**.

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function($) {
               'use strict';
            $('#form').submit(function(event) {  
               event.preventDefault();  
               var url = $(this).attr('action');  
               var datos = $(this).serialize();  
               $.post(url, datos, function(resultado) {  
               $('#result').html(resultado);  
               });  
           });
            </script>
```